# Can SQLite be accessed from another machine?

Tags: sqlite, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to access a SQLite database running on a WP8 app from a Windows 8/Store/"Metro" app?

If yes, how - is there any trick to it? Is it easy, tricky, or impossible?

If impossible, is it possible with any other DB? AFAIK, SQLite is the only DB that can be used with the new Windows Store style sandboxed apps.

Comment: It would be better to explain what you are actually trying to solve rather than asking about getting around what, at first glance, sounds like a restriction with the sandbox. It's not called a "sandbox" for nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Connecting-Windows-8-applications-with-services-Part-1-Using-services-to-get-data-in-our-Windows-8-applications.aspx).  It explains that:

- sqlite is only used for storing data locally (i.e. cache something from a remote data source)
- you cannot connect to remote databases because that involves distributing your database connection string (i.e. username and password) to potentially millions of users
- the correct way to provide data to your app is through some sort of service.  Think about the different APIs major website have now.

So to answer your question: no, this is a bad idea.